# Добавление элементов бинарного дерева в массив

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Как с помощью рекурсии можно добавить все элементы бинарного дерева в массив?

Структура дерева

```
struct node { int data; node* left; node* right; };
```

Comment: а как реализовано дерево?

Comment: struct node
 {
  int data;
  node* left;
  node* right;
 };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По сути вам нужно обойти все элементы дерева. Обходите, например, сначала корень, а потом - рукурсивно - два дочерних поддерева. Или сначала поддеревья, а потом корень. Или одно поддерево, корень, второе...

```
void addToArray(node* root, array& a)
{
    Добавить root->data в a
    if (root->left)  addToArray(root->left,a);
    if (root->right) addToArray(root->right,a);
}
```

Примерно так.

**Update**

Для вектора:

```
void addToArray(node* root, vector<int>& a)
{
    a.push_back(root->data);
    if (root->left)  addToArray(root->left,a);
    if (root->right) addToArray(root->right,a);
}
```

Для C-массива (место выделите сами):

```
void addToArray(node* root, int * a, size_t& idx)
{
    a[idx++] = root->data;
    if (root->left)  addToArray(root->left,a,idx);
    if (root->right) addToArray(root->right,a,idx);
}
```

Вызов:

```
size_t idx = 0;
addToArray(root,a,idx);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Но в моём случае - дело конкретно в записи элементов в бинарное дерево. Обход делаю верно, через cout всё выводится корректно, а вот в массив добавлять не получается.

Comment: В какой массив? Вектор, или обязательно именно массив типа `int a[]`?

Comment: Обязательно именно массив. 

...

Усталость сказывается, такую мелочь не сделать самому. Спасибо за помощь :)